# How to fix the following error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

I wanted to ask a question of code that has grated ja, I have the following code, I am going through a 10x5 array to fill it with number 1, to 49 for a primitive and the function that is responsible for making ticket gives me very rare errors. Index On Bound in theory the function would not have to go out of the way but I do not know what to do if someone can hit me.

```
// It is this part that gives me an error, I have a fly
            int ,c=0;
            int m[][]= new int[10][5];
    
            for (int i=0;i<m.length;i++) {
                for (int x=0;x<m.length;x++,i++) {
                    m[x][i]=c;
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            
            
// This part of code I only have to check if the data output
    // does them correctly
            for(int i=0;i<m[0].length;i++) {
                for(int x=0;x<m.length;x++) {
                    System.out.print(" "+m[i][x]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
    
    El error que me da es siguiente:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
        at provas/provas.main.main(main.java:11)
```

Comment: In English please!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: Sorry guys, i need you help pls

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to fill given array with numbers from `1 to 49`. So you have to pay attention on:

- `int[][] arr = new int[10][5]` creates an `int` array with `10 rows` and `5 columns`
- `arr.length` gives you a total `rows amount`
- `arr[0].length` given you a total `columns amount` at `row 0` *(each row could have different length)*.

```java
public static int[][] fillArray(int[][] arr) {
    int i = 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
            arr[row][col] = i++;

    return arr;
}
```

And finally to print an array:

```java
public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
            System.out.format("%3d", arr[row][col]);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You original method could be like this:

```java
int[][] arr = fillArray(new int[10][5]);
printArray(arr);
```